# Can I use xaml ApplicationResources with an MvvmCross Application

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add some `ApplicationResources` to my `Xamarin` application that uses `MvvmCross`

I currently have an `App.cs` file like so:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Initialize()
    {
       this.CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
        .....etc etc..
    }
}
```

I am now following [Working with Styles using Xaml for your application](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/#Using_Xaml_for_your_App) and have got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mvvmcross="clr-namespace:Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross"
             x:Class="FieldStrikeMove.Core.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application >
```

I also added the `partial` keyword to my `App.cs` class, but this says:

> Partial declarations of must not specify different base classes

So i tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvvmcross:MvxApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mvvmcross="clr-namespace:Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross"
             x:Class="FieldStrikeMove.Core.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</mvvmcross:MvxApplication>
```

but I get:

> Error 35  The type 'FieldStrikeMove.Core.App' cannot be used as type parameter 'TView' in the generic type or method 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(TView, System.Type)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'FieldStrikeMove.Core.App' to 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject'.

Is there a way to have `Xaml` application resources with a `MvvmCross` `Xamarin` application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after @Davids answer I realised that providing a new `App` class was not going to get anywhere.

I found that I could set a `ResourceDictionary` in code behind using

```
Application.Current.ResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
//add styles here
```

I tried to then set this to a Xaml `ResourceDictionary` this in Xaml like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Styles">
  <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but I get

> MyApp.Styles cannot derive from sealed type
>   Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary

(Thanks Xamarin)

**Therefore My Final Solution was this:**

Add a `ContentPage` to My PCL project:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Styles">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
</ContentPage>
```

Then in `MainActivity` after the `LoadApplication` call do:

```
var styles = new Styles();
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources = styles.Resources;
```

Comment: What file you added last two lines? I am getting below error. Any ideas what is missing: Error CS0712 Cannot create an instance of the static class 'Device.Styles'  CS1061 'Device.Styles' does not contain a definition for 'Resources' and no extension method 'Resources' accepting a first argument of type 'Device.Styles' could be found

Comment: @ManishJain That would suggest a new `Device.Styles` class has been added by `Xamarin.Forms` I would suggest fully qualifying it so you would have `new MyApp.Styles()`. The answer here could be slightly improved with the latest `Xamarin.Forms`. This allows you to create your own `ResourceDictionary` and `MergeDictionaries`

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer your looking for but I don't think you can. In fact I dont think you can use Xamarin.Forms application level styles at all with MVVMCross Xaml or otherwise. The styles appear to be implemented from within the Application Class. Application contains a ResourceDictionary and it appears that Application is thus responsible for applying the styles defined in the Dictionary.

MvxApplication has no such Property thus even if you do define them as XAML get them loaded into a ResourceDictionary there is no place I can find that you would apply them.